# Built string in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to build a string to display in a specific cell, that combine some values from other cells and chars.
For example, 
Cell A1= 3
Cell B1 = 2014
I want cell C2 to be the following text:
'3-6/2014

mean:
 "'" + A1 + '-' + (A1+3) + '/' + B1
thanks

Comment: do you want to use vba for this or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the concatenate function.

Based on your description here is a formula to do this for you:

```
=CONCATENATE("'",A1,"-",A1+3,"/",B1)
```

And [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/concatenate-function-HP010062562.aspx) is an explanation of the function. Which I recommend you read.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
="'"&A1&"-"&A1+3&"/"&B1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("'",A1,"-",A1+3,"/",B1)
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.